# Django: Duplicated logic between properties and queryset annotations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

When I want to define my business logic, I'm struggling finding the right way to do this, because I often both need a property AND a custom queryset to get the same info. In the end, the logic is duplicated.

#### Let me explain...

First, after defining my class, I naturally start writing a simple property for data I need:

```
class PickupTimeSlot(models.Model):

    @property
    def nb_bookings(self) -> int:
        """ How many times this time slot is booked? """ 
        return self.order_set.validated().count()
```

Then, I quickly realise that calling this property while dealing with many objects in a queryset will lead to duplicated queries and will kill performance (even if I use prefetching, because filtering is called again). So I solve the problem writing a custom queryset with annotation:

```
class PickupTimeSlotQuerySet(query.QuerySet):

    def add_nb_bookings_data(self):
        return self.annotate(db_nb_bookings=Count('order', filter=Q(order__status=Order.VALIDATED)))
```

#### The issue

And then, I end up with 2 problems:

- I have the same business logic ("*how to find the number of bookings*") written twice, that could lead to functional errors.
- I need to find two different attribute names to avoid conflicts, because obviously, setting `nb_bookings` for both the property and the annotation don't work. This forces me, when using my object, to think about **how** the data is generated, to call the right attribute name (let's say `pickup_slot.nb_bookings` (property) or `pickup_slot.db_nb_bookings` (annotation) )

This seems poorly designed to me, and I'm pretty sure there is a way to do better. I'd need a way to always write `pickup_slot.nb_bookings` and having a performant answer, always using the same business logic.

#### I have an idea, but I'm not sure...

I was thinking of completely removing the property and keeking custom queryset only. Then, for single objects, wrapping them in querysets just to be able to call add annotation data on it. Something like:

`pickup_slot = PickupTimeSlot.objects.add_nb_bookings_data().get(pk=pickup_slot.pk)`

Seems pretty hacky and unnatural to me. What do you think?

Comment: Great question. Relevant ticket on the Django project: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28822.

Comment: Sometimes the `property` implementation is easier when you have a large dataset in your DB (say 1M), coz, at that point, the annotation will become slower since you are performing the query over 1M records.

Comment: IMHO, keep both logic in your code as long as they returning the same result. and lets wait for the *"official"* implementation.

Comment: Just asking: Wouldn't this work to get a specific record? `pickup_slot = PickupTimeSlot.objects.filter(pk=pickup_slot.pk).add_nb_bookings_data()[0]` I imagine that the annotation will be done only to one record, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your different good answers, I decided to stick with annotations **and** properties. I created a cache mechanism to make it transparent about the naming. The main advantage is to keep the business logic in one place only.
The only drawback I see is that an object could be called from database a second time to be annotated. Performance impact stays minor IMO.

Here is a full example with 3 different attributes I need in my model.
Feel free to comment to improve this.

#### models.py

```
class PickupTimeSlotQuerySet(query.QuerySet):

    def add_booking_data(self):
        return self \
            .prefetch_related('order_set') \
            .annotate(_nb_bookings=Count('order', filter=Q(order__status=Order.VALIDATED))) \
            .annotate(_nb_available_bookings=F('nb_max_bookings') - F('_nb_bookings')) \
            .annotate(_is_bookable=Case(When(_nb_bookings__lt=F('nb_max_bookings'),
                                             then=Value(True)),
                                        default=Value(False),
                                        output_field=BooleanField())
                      ) \
            .order_by('start')

class PickupTimeSlot(models.Model):
    objects = SafeDeleteManager.from_queryset(PickupTimeSlotQuerySet)()
   
    nb_max_bookings = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    @annotate_to_property('add_booking_data', 'nb_bookings')
    def nb_bookings(self):
        pass
    
    @annotate_to_property('add_booking_data', 'nb_available_bookings')
    def nb_available_bookings(self):
        pass
    
    @annotate_to_property('add_booking_data', 'is_bookable')
    def is_bookable(self):
        pass
```

#### decorators.py

```
def annotate_to_property(queryset_method_name, key_name):
    """
    allow an annotated attribute to be used as property.
    """
    from django.apps import apps

    def decorator(func):
        def inner(self):
            attr = "_" + key_name
            if not hasattr(self, attr):
                klass = apps.get_model(self._meta.app_label,
                                       self._meta.object_name)
                to_eval = f"klass.objects.{queryset_method_name}().get(pk={self.pk}).{attr}"
                value = eval(to_eval, {'klass': klass})
                setattr(self, attr, value)

            return getattr(self, attr)

        return property(inner)

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is a silver bullet here. But I use this pattern in my projects for such cases.

```
class PickupTimeSlotAnnotatedManager(models.Manager):
    def with_nb_bookings(self):
        return self.annotate(
            _nb_bookings=Count(
                'order', filter=Q(order__status=Order.VALIDATED)
            )
        )

class PickupTimeSlot(models.Model):
    ...
    annotated = PickupTimeSlotAnnotatedManager()

    @property
    def nb_bookings(self) -> int:
        """ How many times this time slot is booked? """ 
        if hasattr(self, '_nb_bookings'):
            return self._nb_bookings
        return self.order_set.validated().count()
```

In code

```
qs = PickupTimeSlot.annotated.with_nb_bookings()
for item in qs:
    print(item.nb_bookings)
```

This way I can always use property, if it is part of annotated queryset it will use annotated value if not it will calculate it. This approach guaranties that I will have full control of when to make queryset "heavier" by annotating it with required values. If I don't need this I just use regular `PickupTimeSlot.objects. ...`

Also if there are many such properties you could write decorator that will wrap property and simplify code. It will work as `cached_property` decorator, but instead it will use annotated value if it is present.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like an acceptable compromise to me. An idea: in the property, what do you think of returning `PickupTimeSlot.objects.with_nb_bookings().get(pk=self.pk)._nb_bookings` to avoid logic duplication? (rather than `self.order_set.validated().count()`)

Comment: You could do that, but you already have that object, getting `nb_bookings` by refetching same object from db with annotated data have "smelly" look to me personally. But this is subjective.

Comment: You're right it's ugly. However I think I can almost always manage to call `with_nb_bookings()` before the `get()` on my object, so this should not happen a lot. But I'm thinking I would not need a property at all in that case. And this would solve the issue of double name (`_nb_bookings` VS `nb_booking`)

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't need property in this case, but it may be confusing for future readers of your code if there will be an attribute error, it may take some time to find out where `nb_bookings` coming from. Either way there is no beautiful solution for this for now, so do what works better for you and your project.

Comment: I posted an answer, mainly based on yours, containing the decorator you talked about. Feel free to comment if you notice any improvement idea. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

- Do you need to filter the *"annotated field"* results?

  - If Yes, ***"Keep"*** the manager and **use it when required**. In *any other situation*, use property logic
  - If No, remove the manager/annotation process and stick with property implementation, unless your table is small (~1000 entries) and not growing over the period.
- The only advantage of *annotation* process I am seeing here is the filtering capability on the database level of the data

---

I have conducted a few tests to reach the conclusion, here they are

#### Environment

- Django 3.0.7
- Python 3.8
- PostgreSQL 10.14

#### Model Structure

For the sake of simplicity and simulation, I am following the below model representation

```
class ReporterManager(models.Manager):
    def article_count_qs(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(
            annotate_article_count=models.Count('articles__id', distinct=True))


class Reporter(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    counter_manager = ReporterManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @property
    def article_count(self):
        return self.articles.distinct().count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="articles")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

I have populated my database, both `Reporter` and `Article` model with random strings.

- Reporter rows **~220K** (220514)
- Article rows **~1M** (997311)

### Test Cases

1. Random picking of `Reporter` instance and retrieves the *article count*. We usually do this in the **Detail View**
2. A paginated result. We *slice* the queryset and *iterates* over the sliced queryset.
3. Filtering

I am using the [**`%timeit`**-(ipython doc)](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) command of `Ipython` shell to calculate the execution time

#### Test Case 1

For this, I have created these functions, which randomly pick instances from the database

```
import random

MAX_REPORTER = 220514


def test_manager_random_picking():
    pos = random.randint(1, MAX_REPORTER)
    return Reporter.counter_manager.article_count_qs()[pos].annotate_article_count


def test_property_random_picking():
    pos = random.randint(1, MAX_REPORTER)
    return Reporter.objects.all()[pos].article_count
```

**Results**

```
In [2]: %timeit test_manager_random_picking()
8.78 s ± 6.1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit test_property_random_picking()
6.36 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### Test Case 2

I have created another two functions,

```
import random

PAGINATE_SIZE = 50


def test_manager_paginate_iteration():
    start = random.randint(1, MAX_REPORTER - PAGINATE_SIZE)
    end = start + PAGINATE_SIZE
    qs = Reporter.counter_manager.article_count_qs()[start:end]
    for reporter in qs:
        reporter.annotate_article_count


def test_property_paginate_iteration():
    start = random.randint(1, MAX_REPORTER - PAGINATE_SIZE)
    end = start + PAGINATE_SIZE
    qs = Reporter.objects.all()[start:end]
    for reporter in qs:
        reporter.article_count
```

**Results**

```
In [8]: %timeit test_manager_paginate_iteration()
4.99 s ± 312 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [9]: %timeit test_property_paginate_iteration()
47 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Test Case 3

undoubtedly, annotation is the only way here

Here you can see, the **annotation** process takes a huge amount of time as compared to the property implementation.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any duplication, one option could be:

- remove the property in the Model
- use a custom Manager
- override it's get_queryset() method:

```
class PickupTimeSlotManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            db_nb_bookings=Count(
                'order', filter=Q(order__status=Order.VALIDATED)
            )
        )
```

```
from django.db import models
from .managers import PickupTimeSlotManager

class PickupTimeSlot(models.Model):
    ...
    # Add custom manager
    objects = PickupTimeSlotManager()
```

**advantage**: the calculated properties is transparently added to any queryset; no further action is required to use it

**disadvantage**: the computational overhead occurs even when the calculated property is not used

Comment: putting the annotation along with the ***default*** manager isn't recommended. AFAIK, Django will do an annotation ***each time*** whenever you call the object using the `.` (dot) operator

Comment: @ArakkalAbu do you mean that the same annotation will be added multiple times to the queryset ? Why ?

Comment: [I haven't done test] I think that is the ***`N+1`*** problem. Just to clarify, "by accessing the ***related objects*** using dot operator" @Mario Orlandi

Comment: I suspect the opposite: you might more likely incur in a N+1 problem when using a property in the single Model, then when annotating the whole queryset. This might also depend on how smart is the ORM in expressing the annotation at SQL level; having the full Model code available, would be interesting to inspect it as follows: print(str(queryset.query))

Comment: You're right. The `property` implementation will case `N+1` problem, but, the annotation doesn't.

Comment: Right. You'll still have an additional cost when building the queryset, as I listed under "disadvantage". How much this cost is significant depends on the specific context

Answer (score 1):

Let this be the alternative way to archive what you want:

Since I usually add the `prefetch_related` every time I write a queryset. So when I face this problem, I will use Python to solve this problem.

I'm going to use Python to loop and count the data for me instead of doing it in SQL way.

```
class PickupTimeSlot(models.Model):

    @property
    def nb_bookings(self) -> int:
        """ How many times this time slot is booked? """ 
        orders = self.order_set.all()  # this won't hit the database if you already did the prefetch_related
        validated_orders = filter(lambda x: x.status == Order.VALIDATED, orders)
        return len(validated_orders)
```

And most important thing, `prefetch_related`:

```
time_slots = PickupTimeSlot.objects.prefetch_related('order_set').all()
```

You may have a question that why I didn't `prefetch_related` with filtered queryset so Python doesn't need to filter again like:

```
time_slots = PickupTimeSlot.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('order_set', queryset=Order.objects.filter(status=Order.VALIDATED))
).all()
```

The answer is there are sometimes that we also need the other information from `orders` as well. Doing the first way will not cost anything more if we're going to prefetch it anyway.

Hope this more or less helps you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a good idea to prevent filtering again for orders. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this solution seems to be very context-specific since the Python `filter()` method could be called many times, for example if there are many PickupTimeSlot objects. For each of these object, it would recompute the validated_orders (that are always the same).

Comment: @DavidD. Yes, you're right. Maybe I usually use this in serializer instead of the model. So it will be filtered only once. Nice talk BTW :)